# How to show that $p^{2 \times}(n)=p^{3k\pm1}(n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ partitions

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

$p^{2 \times}(n)=p^{3k\pm1}(n)$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$p^{2 \times}(n),$ where $n\in\mathbb{N},$ is the number of the partitions of $n$ such that each number can appear as at most two summands.

$p^{3k\pm1}(n),$ where $n\in\mathbb{N},$ is the number of partitions of $n$ where each summand is not divisible by $3.$

I know that I should find the generating functions in both cases, but I still don't know how does it work in this special case

Comment: I mean that for example $4=3+1$ is not a good partition, because 3 is divisible by 3 or $6=3+2+1$ because 3 is again divisible by 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function for $p^{2 \times}(n)$ is given by 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p^{2 \times}(n) x^n = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1+x^{i}+x^{2i}).
\end{eqnarray*}
The generating function for $p^{3k\pm1}(n)$ is given by 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p^{3k\pm1}(n) x^n = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-x^{3i-2})}\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-x^{3i-1})}.  
\end{eqnarray*}
To observe that these are equal, rearrange the terms in the first product as follows
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & \prod_{j=1, 3 \nmid j }^{\infty} \, \,\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}(1+x^{j3^{k}}+x^{2j3^{k}}) \\
&=&\prod_{j=1, 3 \nmid j }^{\infty} (1+x^{j}+x^{2j}+x^{3j}+x^{4j}+\cdots ) \\
&=&\prod_{j=1, 3 \nmid j }^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1-x^{j})}.
\end{eqnarray*}